# How to create Spring RESTFul Service Using Java Configuration?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a Spring 4 RESTFul Service using Java Configuration and deploy to Tomcat.  But I am not able to hit the endpoint.  What am I missing?  This is what I have.

I have a Greeting POJO that has setters and getters.

```
public class Greeting {
    private BigInteger id;
    private String text;

    //setters and getters
}
```

I have a Greeting Controller.

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

  private static BigInteger nextId;
  private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;

  //have some code to store Greetings in greetingMap

  @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings() {
      Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();
      return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings, HttpStatus.OK);
  }

}
```

I have a Configuration class.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "org.example")
  public class GreetingConfiguration {

}
```

And this is my src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

  <display-name>Spring Application</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>org.example.ws.configuration.GreetingConfiguration</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>dispatchOptionsRequest</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>org.example.ws.configuration.GreetingConfiguration</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
```

I deployed to tomcat.  Tomcat starts ok. I tried to hit it http://localhost:8080/api/greetings , it gives me 404.  What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Try replacing `@Controller` with `@RestController` Are you able to access a welcome page in your application? No root context? And use `/*` for url-pattern.

Comment: i think you have problem in `GreetingConfiguration`.

Answer (score 1):

You are combining XML and Java configuration. So, you need to tell Spring to pick up controller annotations by one of the two methods:

1. @EnableWebMvc in your configuration class
2. Or,  in XML

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add @ResponseBody to your rest method

```
 @Controller
    public class GreetingController {

      private static BigInteger nextId;
      private static Map<BigInteger, Greeting> greetingMap;

      //have some code to store Greetings in greetingMap

      @RequestMapping(value = "/api/greetings", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
      @ResponseBody
      public ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>> getGreetings() {
          Collection<Greeting> greetings = greetingMap.values();
          return new ResponseEntity<Collection<Greeting>>(greetings, HttpStatus.OK);
      }

    }
```

and check that you have jackson databinding dependency in your pom.xml